# Difference between git push origin prod AND git push origin prod:refs/heads/prod

Tags: git, git-branch

When I create a new branch and then want to push it remotely, I can do:

> git push origin prod

OR

> git push origin prod:refs/heads/prod

What is the difference ?

Answer (score 2):

On vanilla configurations, there would be no difference.

However, remotes can be configured with custom push branch specifications in .git/config. In that case, specifying the explicit ref name on the server end like `local_ref_name:remote_ref_name` overrides the configured mappings.

If you had *just added* a new remote, and wanted to push for the first time, you would *need* to at least specify the branch to push. In that case

```
git push origin prod
git push origin prod:prod
git push origin prod:refs/heads/prod
```

would all have been equivalent. Final trivia:

```
git push origin :prod
```

will *delete* the ref named `prod` on the remote end.

Comment: For deleting the colon needs to be in front of the remote branch name, not after it.

Comment: @qqx quite right, fixed (rationale: push the empty ref to `prod`)